# Javascript what is "index" within an argument?

Tags: javascript

```
 var g = document.getElementById('my_div');
for (var i = 0, len = g.children.length; i < len; i++)
{

    (function(index){
        g.children[i].onclick = function(){
              alert(index)  ;
        }    
    })(i);

}
```

So I saw the above example that shows how to get the index of the clicked element. I noticed that it uses "index" as a parameter. Unfortunately I am only aware of indexof so how does this work? I cant find anything about "index" when googling: javascript index property or javascript index argument.

Edit: I really didnt see the function call with (i) as it was so small.

Comment: It's just a variable name actually! Nothing special.

Comment: `index` is what `i` is called when it's passed into the IIFE (to avoid scoping issues with the event listener).

Comment: `index` contains the `i` value in the `for`.

Comment: @Andy but there is no meaning to this variable so how does it work? It has no value. I mean I dont see var index = something;

Comment: This `(function(index)...)(i)` defines local function and calls it immediately passing i as its index argument.

Comment: Ok nevermind. It was really hard to see (i)

Comment: @c-smile ya I just noticed (i). Really embarassing. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer and comments are correct, `index` in this case is just a function argument, but I'll (try) to explain a bit more what's going on here.

As others have said, `index` is just a variable, in this case the argument to the function. There's nothing special about the name `index` here, it could have been `argument1` or `vader` :-), or whatever.

So what's happening is that this function is being declared:

```
function(arg1){
        g.children[i].onclick = function(){
              alert(arg1)  ;
        }    
    }
```

I've replaced `index` with `arg1` to show that `index` isn't special, although it works fine with `index`. After that function's declared, it's being *called* by wrapping it in parens, and then passing the argument `i` (the `(i)`). This calls the function, assigning the current value of `i` to the first argument to the function, `arg1` here, or `index` in the original. The function declares *another* function, this time

```
function() {alert(arg1);}
```

and assigns it to the onclick handler of the `i'th` element of the `g.children` array. So each onclick handler will be a function that just does an alert of the index of the array element.

If you step through the loop in a debugger, you'll see it effectively does:

```
g.children[0].onclick = function(){ alert(0); };
g.children[1].onclick = function(){ alert(1); };
g.children[2].onclick = function(){ alert(2); };
```

etc.

Comment: Im so embarrassed. I am so extremely tired (1 am) that I overlooked this extremely simple function call. Should my question be deleted or should I keep it in case someone else has trouble?

Comment: @Asperger I'd leave it. Even though you get it (and don't be embarrassed, everyone that's been programming for more than a few minutes has situations where they just don't get something until someone points out the obvious :-) ), someone else may not, and there's a bit going on here that's somewhat unique to JavaScript.

Comment: Whew! Worst things happened before! I guess I need to buy a rubber duck and talk to it

Answer (score 1):

the code:

```
 (function(index){
        g.children[i].onclick = function(){
              alert(index)  ;
        }    
    })(i);
```

is an auto-executed function, which is called with value's argument **i**.

**Simple example**:

```
function a(arg1) {
    console.log(arg1);
}
a(10); //console.log(10);
```

You can do this with that way:

```
(function (arg1) {
  console.log(arg1);
})(10); //console.log(10);
```

Comment: Oh boy. this is so embarrassing. This happens when you code at 1 am in the morning : (

Comment: Eventhough im aware of it I will accept your answer since its nicely formatted.

Comment: No no, not at all.  I accepted the answer above since its more detailed but upvoted yours as well.